# Generic function for creating and returning a generic array of objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Everytime I think I have understood the generics, I come up with a task which proves me wrong. This is what I want:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBMBiBOBXAlsAzlKBeKByAhmGADYS5QA+eA9vPgHYDmZlek+8uA3AFCiQwAwhwyZsbCIkbVg5KrgC2EeAGMIAEwhpc8+sjRoG3PuGhxi1AO7KMOXPGpoW84ImLIwcvADdk1UrK8JgLAAIIGEOjiAN48mMgK+MwAXFDRAL4ANHEwEAAewKkZ2ek8wWYIKGERUeLVTlEAZGlQyOqpcEioGKX8ZsLw4Q2imDj1kRjN0a3tQiJQvaYwsBbWgzW2MEMTUFMzHStWNgtlPCrU9GjAUCrwEPjAENtROAA8ACqZUACqAHwAFG00KlvgBtAC6AEpku8IdhfmkcphzpdrvgNjC4TgIUExFAAGa0KD-FFXKDqB74ACS6ig1HxMzQkNieMwAHo2VB3qY0LcPNd1NQtPRcNd3ABrMwAC30ySRrPRwwAdGBEGgpf8WaztW1UhTgNT1NltTrEilivKTbkCsCLVb0pDeHjSvK7q54PQoIqJrwXaTrviuuNajhbvdHs80K9OlVI18Y90AaCCERSLhMrhaAxmOncOxOFDeP6bhxI3jQ3cHk8NtGBnG5vA0Em85JpLIM0pVBotLm9AYjIWzhcyfjVsoyxXw9XhtHDmt6+Yjo3mw4nLnXO5PBnfP5IrhC0A)

```
type tFruits  = 'apple' | 'orange' | 'pear';
type tCars    = 'peugot' | 'mercedes'| 'nissan';
type tFlowers = 'rose' | 'tulip' | 'violet';

type tAssets = {
  image: {},
  text: {},
}

type tFruitAssets  = tAssets & { id: tFruits }
type tCarAssets    = tAssets & { id: tCars }
type tFlowerAssets = tAssets & { id: tFlowers }


const createAssets = <T, U>(ids: U[]):T[] => {
    const assets:T[] = [];

    for (const dataId of ids){
      // Typescript doesn't like this:
        assets.push({
            id: dataId,
            image:{},
            text:{},
        });
    }

    return assets;
}

const fruitAssets  = createAssets<tFruitAssets, tFruits>(['apple','orange','pear']);
const carAssets    = createAssets<tCarAssets, tCars>(['peugot','mercedes','nissan']);
const flowerAssets = createAssets<tFlowerAssets, tFlowers>(['rose','tulip','violet']);
```

Typescript doesn't like the object I try to push to the assets array inside my createAssets functions. It says:

```
Argument of type '{ id: U; image: {}; texts: {}; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ id: U; image: {}; texts: {}; }'.
```

Could someone please explain me how I have to change the function? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `T` could be other type like  `tAssets & { id: tFruits } & { anotherId: tFruits }` which is not compatible with `tAssets & { id: tFruits }`  like the  `createAssets` do.

`createAssets` say it can create `T[]` from `U[]`, but it actually only create  `(tAssets & { id: U })[]` from `U[]`.If `T` includes `anotherId`, `createAssets` will not return it and this may cause error.

```
type tFruits = 'apple' | 'orange' | 'pear';
type tAssets = {
    image: {};
    text: {};
};
type FruitAssets = tAssets & { id: tFruits };
type OtherFruitAssets = FruitAssets & { anotherId: tFruits };
//works
const tFruitAssets: FruitAssets[] = createAssets<FruitAssets, tFruits>(['apple']);
//not work properly,but will not throw type error here
//expect otherTFruitAssets to be type OtherFruitAssets[]
//but actually otherTFruitAssets will be FruitAssets[] and this may cause error
const otherTFruitAssets: OtherFruitAssets[] = createAssets<OtherFruitAssets, tFruits>(['apple']);
```

What `createAssets` do is create `(tAssets & { id: U })[]` from `U[]`, so its type should be:

```
const createAssets = <U,>(ids: U[]): (tAssets & { id: U })[] => {
    const assets: (tAssets & { id: U })[] = [];
    for (const dataId of ids) {
        assets.push({
            id: dataId,
            image: {},
            text: {},
        });
    }
    return assets;
};
```

Comment: `const fruitAssets: tFruitAssets = createAssets<tFruits>(['apple','orange','pear']);` not works because `fruitAssets` should be `tFruitAssets[]`. Could you give me some other example which is not suitable for your case.

Comment: You are right. I am confused by our own types already. I should go to sleep. I deleted my comment to prevent confusion. I inserted your function and I have no errors. I will run some tests. I am still checking if I can ignore your `OtherFruitAssets` example.

Answer (score 0):

10 Minutes later I came up with this:

```
// [...]

const createAssets = <T, U>(ids: U[]):T[] => {
    const assets:T[] = [];

    for (const dataId of ids){
        const t = {
            id: dataId,
            image:{},
            text:{},
        } as T;
        assets.push(t);
    }

    return assets;
}
```

Typescript is satisfied now but I feel like as if it would be more of a workaround than a proper solution. Am I fooling myself here?

Comment: Is that a typo? `texts` vs `text`. I'm going to assume it is...

Comment: It is. Corrected it. Thank you for pointing at it. It even was in the question.

Answer (score 0):

While you could assert it and be done with it for now,

```
const createAssets = <T, U>(ids: U[]): T[] => {
    const assets: T[] = [];

    for (const dataId of ids) {
        const t = {
            id: dataId,
            image: {},
            texts: {},
        } as T;

        assets.push(t);
    }

    return assets;
};
```

this is actually unsound because the caller chooses the type of `T` and `U`, which means this passes type-checking:

```
const fruitAssets = createAssets<tCarAssets, tFruits>(["apple", "orange", "pear"]);
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^ should be invalid
```

You can easily make it safer by adding constraints to the generic parameters.

```
const createAssets = <T extends tAssets & { id: U }, U extends string>(ids: U[]): T[] => {
```

However, now you will have to use `as unknown as T` because TypeScript sees the possibility that someone may use

```
createAssets<{ id: string; image: {}; text: {}; extraProperty: {} }, string>(...);
//                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ extra property here
```

which means that pushing `t` to `assets` is unsound, since you would be missing that extra property. If you *really* wanted to, you could also prevent this from happening by changing the constraints a little...

```
const createAssets = <T extends tAssets & { id: U }, U extends (tAssets & { id: U } extends T ? string : never)>(ids: U[]): T[] => {
```

Unfortunately, with all of these in place, the assertion is still necessary.
You could try to make it a little cleaner (get rid of the double assertion) with `map`:

```
const createAssets = <T extends tAssets & { id: U }, U extends (tAssets & { id: U } extends T ? string : never)>(ids: U[]): T[] => {
    const assets = ids.map((id) => ({ id, image: {}, text: {} })) as T[];

    return assets;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBMBiBOBXAlsAzlAvFARAQzDABsIcoAfXAe3jwDsBzUi3SPeHAbgChRIYAwuwzYckRAyrAylHAFsI8AMYQAJhDQzcdZGjT0uvcNDhEqAd0Ujc8KmmazgiIsjBacAN2RUS0nkf5gAEE9CHQsKABvbihYqGQ5PCYALiiAXx44mAgAD2BUyIzuIoCTBBRg0PDsSvtwgDIo+NVUuCRUDCK+EyF4ELrrWrCMRsjm1t7Onm6YWDNLPqrB-uGoUfHZ+asoEqUqOjRgKCV4CDxgCBXqqAAeABUoXIu6VQwhhqbkFqgAVR2AGl+jzyEBeGAAFO8Rp9vn80sDnq8oA8APxQQ7wZCMKCpOgQDyKACUAD5wV80KkfgBtAC6hNSd1pWGJURicT2ByOeCWEXJADpEmBwWTVITmVBwWMvoCEkkIAU0oCLnkFTtCWLucjaf4sqcnPA6FBuQMeCUAPRmqAAIzwqkBcl0iWASgAFmoYMY0NwOYcoAAzdpQiInM4XK5oG7AXrhpXlDqkqn4QgkHCAnA0ehMVOsM4cOk8C3W22Ap60KBgWyQeCgb37X1Kdjh4Onc6XJY3KXfDFYhiceKJFLpPvK-JDhG0AAKlcUoFVivRwExjATYggEik2fkihU6k0aZ0egM+e4hckVFUtc5-q2iwGzdDbYGkbmFkUMc2r-gaBXtnsm6cLhuGmXg+GEODHkAA)

Comment: The problem I got with your function is that I cannot add anything to text or image. Try to add `foo: 'bar'` to the text object for example.